# How can I print an array while keepping the indentation?

Tags: java

I have this array that shows the user the indexes of the position on a board of a game I'm making, the board is hexagonal and the notations bellow aren't finished yet because I'm to lazy to finish them right now :), but I'm wondering how can I print it on the console while keeping the format.
Thanks in advance

```
public static final String[] NOTATION = {
            "     0/4 0/6 0/8 0/10 0/12         ",
            "    1/3 1/5 1/7 1/9 1/11 1/13      ",
            "   2/2 2/4 2/6 2/8 2/10 2/12 2/14  ",
            "  F + + + + + + + +  ",
            " E + + + + + + + + + ",
            "  D + + + + + + + + 9",
            "   C + + + + + + + 8 ",
            "    B + + + + + + 7  ",
            "     A + + + + + 6   ",
            "        1 2 3 4 5    "
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend making a method you can call that prints it so you can print it easily many times, for example `printBoard`:

```
public static void printBoard() {
    for (String str : NOTATION) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

This utilizes an enhanced `for` loop to iterate through the array, and print each `String` moving to the next line with `println`.

Use it with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printBoard();
}
```

**Output:**

```
     0/4 0/6 0/8 0/10 0/12         
    1/3 1/5 1/7 1/9 1/11 1/13      
   2/2 2/4 2/6 2/8 2/10 2/12 2/14  
  F + + + + + + + +  
 E + + + + + + + + + 
  D + + + + + + + + 9
   C + + + + + + + 8 
    B + + + + + + 7  
     A + + + + + 6   
        1 2 3 4 5
```

Note:  I recommend reworking this into not using `static` and instead using OOP in something like a `Board` class.